# Python attribute error when using sqlite cursor from class

Tags: python

I am trying to fix an issue I am having but can't seem to find the issue. I need to create a Python class for handling database interactions. So far I have done something like this, but I am getting an AttributeError which I could not resolve.

```
import sqlite3


class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self.file = 'database.db'
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.file)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def query(self, query, *args):
        try:
            self.cur.execute(query, args)
            self.conn.commit()
            self.conn.close()
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print(e)
```

I then run the following command:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES (?);'
Database.query(sql, "ABC")
```

But get this error message:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cur'
```

Please help me figure this out :D Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to initiate your object before using it:

```
db = Database()
db.query(sql, "ABC")
```